# Can someone help me with this true or false problem?

Tags: calculus, integration

My exam is tomorrow and I don't understand this concept. Someone please help!

[image: Calculus]

Comment: What concept is troubling you?  You did note the reversed limits of integration at the end, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integrals have the properties that they are additive, constants can "jump out", and changing the sign can is the same as switching the limits. Namely:

1. $\displaystyle\int_a^b(cf+g) = c\int_a^b f+\int_a^b g$
2. $\displaystyle\int_a^b f = -\int_b^a f$

From these two properties the question should be clearer.

Comment: Thank you. This did make it clearer.

Comment: @David, my pleasure. Good luck tomorrow.